# Using Xcode UI testing, is it possible to get the value of a secureTextFields element without receiving dots ("•••••")?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I'm working on a project where the UI test has a password field. The password is initially hidden, and the test checks to see if the value of the secureTextField is "••••••••".

```
// This works    
let passwordValue = getValueOf(passwordTextField)
XCTAssertEqual(passwordSecureTextFieldValue, "••••••••")
```

Next, the password is revealed by tapping an eye icon that shows the password to the user as normal text, not dots. From there, I'd like to assert that the value of of the secureTextField is "password". Is there a property or strategy to do that?

Comment: When you click on the eye, do this ``yourTextField.secureTextEntry = false`` and then get pass the value to some variable like ``x = yourTextField.text ?? ""`` and then compare?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option: `Value of type 'XCUIElement' has no member 'secureTextEntry'`